# Google Line chart, remove extra lines

Tags: google-visualization, linegraph

I am new in Google Graphs and I am attemting to generate this graph in the photo ( expected ) below
but I am getting a little bit different graph. I have three different letters and each letter contains their own values (A1, A2, A3, B1, B2 ... e.g.).

There the code which I am trying:

```
function drawChart () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('string', 'Type');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');

    data.addRows([
    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'A', 75],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'A', 100],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'A', 125],

    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'A', 75],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'A', 100],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'A', 125],

    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'B', 150],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'B', 175],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 30), 'B', 200],

    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'B', 150],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'B', 175],
    [new Date(2014, 0, 31), 'B', 200],
]);

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'A',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'A') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'B',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'B') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }, {
        type: 'number',
        label: 'C',
        calc: function (dt, row) {
            return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'C') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
        }
    }, 2]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(view, {
        height: 400,
        width: 600,
        hAxis: {
            format: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            minValue: new Date(2014, 0, 29, 12),
            maxValue: new Date(2014, 0, 31, 10)
        },
        series: {
            0: {
                // series A options
                pointSize: 5,
                lineWidth: 0

            },

            3: {
                // this series draws the line
                pointSize: 0,
                lineWidth: 1,
                visibleInLegend: false,
                enableInteractivity: false,
                color:'blue'
            }
        }
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

And it showing me this and I don't know how remove a line in 31.01.2014 -> A3 with 30.01.2014->B1 and color of line for blue dots blue color and for red dots red line is it possible? :

[image]

But expected one is below :

[image]

Comment: Please share the code you've tried, and why it doesn't work.

Comment: jmac I added code which I am trying, it would be better if you help me. Thanks

Comment: Is it difficult to generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where my answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467458/multi-value-in-one-line-google-graph) is not the best approach to take for this, but there is an easy solution to modify your existing code to make this work.  Remove the `2` from the end of the array passed to `view.setColumns`:

```
view.setColumns([0, {
    type: 'number',
    label: 'A',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'A') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    }
}, {
    type: 'number',
    label: 'B',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'B') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    }
}, {
    type: 'number',
    label: 'C',
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        return (dt.getValue(row, 1) == 'C') ? dt.getValue(row, 2) : null;
    }
}]);
```

and adjust your series options:

```
series: {
    0: {
        // series A options
        pointSize: 5,
        lineWidth: 1
    },
    1: {
        // series B options
        pointSize: 5,
        lineWidth: 1
    },
    2: {
        // series C options
        pointSize: 5,
        lineWidth: 1
    }
}
```

Comment: asgallant thank you very much it is working! And now I need to implement it to my project, I need to generate json and give this data through the "DataTable" what is the data structure in php array? As I asked my previous question I gave a sample php array. E.g

Comment: Are you asking what the structure is in general, or how to replicate your DataTable specifically?

Comment: Yes, I want to know how would be data structure, I will get data from array and is it possible use this script dynamically I mean user will select some options and depending this options the array will be generated there may be 5 letters ( A, B, C, D, E ) and now everything is hard coded, I don't know how many letters will be I mean I don't know how many series will be

Comment: What programming language are you using for building the DataTable?

Comment: I am using PHP and for database MySQL

Comment: Open a new question for this, including the database structure and the format you need the data to be in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46591/discussion-between-umidjon-urunov-and-asgallant)